# Array elements displayed in Listbox are displayed not correctly

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, listbox

First of all; I cannot use list. It has to be a array for school purposes.
I have a `string[] Brands = new string[10];` Four elements of this array are already filled when the form is initialized. The empty elements can be filled by adding textbox value to array with `btnclick` I'm displaying the filled elements in a listbox. The problem is that the listbox displays it like this:

Kawasaki
Yamaha
Harley
Suzuki

It needs to be displayed like this:
Kawasaki Yamaha Harley Suzuki
(when i click the buttun it needs to the already existing elementsd like this)
Kawasaki Yamaha Harley Suzuki (the added value1)

Another btnclick:
Kawasaki Yamaha Harley Suzuki (the added value1) (the added value2)

I know I need to use a `for loop` in my `btnclik` but I don't know how. This is what I currently have in my `btnclick` event:

```
if (brandNr >= 10)
   return;

Brands[brandNr++] = textBoxBrand.Text;
listBoxMotorcycles.DataSource = null;
listBoxMotorcycles.DataSource = Brands;
```

Comment: Why are you using a listbox if you don't want to display the elements as a list?

Comment: I know it's strange but I need to use it like this for school.

I need to use a array with fixed length > add values to aray with textbox > display the values in a listbox

Comment: What doesn't work in your solution?

Comment: The listbox displays the values as a list but it needs to display it as increments.

Comment: I really doubt in your school make you use a listbox to display elements horizontally,just doesn't make sense to me..you should use a textbox or a label for the output array

Comment: Pikoh, I know it sounds strange, but believe me. My teachter wants me to display it horizontally.

Comment: So, I'm assuming this isn't for a functional use but just to demonstrate that you understand how to loop through the array and get the elements. Have you made any attempt with this for loop to do that? It would be nothing more than taking the iterator (typically i when using the snippet) and using it as the index number and then concatenating the result to a string variable. Making sure to start at the first element and not to exceed the last.

Comment: Are you using WinForms, or WPF for the UI? In WPF, you might be able to set the listbox flow direction and orientation to make it horizontal, but I'm not sure how to do this in WinForms. The list box is never designed to be used that way. Essentially, to acheive what you want in a list box, you have to add a single element, and when a new one is added to the array, you have to get the content of the element at position 0, replace it with the contents of the array, clear the list box contents and add the new content.

Comment: Yes, it's pure to demonstrate it. Could you show me the example of the FOR loop you are proposing?

Comment: I don't think that is possible in windows forms. The only way i can think of archieving it would be having just one item in the listbox and concatenating all the elements of the array in that item...

Comment: type for and hit the [Tab] key twice

Answer (score 1):

first of all make sure that for form is wider enough, then on the load event you can write this code

```
 Brands[0] = "Kawasaki";
 Brands[1] = "Yamaha";
 Brands[2] = "Harley";
 Brands[3] = "Suzuki";
 listBoxMotorcycles.MultiColumn = true;
 listBoxMotorcycles.ColumnWidth = 100;
 listBoxMotorcycles.Width  = 400;
 listBoxMotorcycles.Height = 20;
 listBoxMotorcycles.DataSource = Brands;
```

and on the button click event your code must be he follwing

```
if(listBoxMotorcycles.Items.Count < Brands.Length)
{
    Brands[listBoxMotorcycles.Items.Count] = textBox1.Text;
    listBoxMotorcycles.DataSource = null;
    listBoxMotorcycles.DataSource = Brands;

    textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
}
```